# How to check if date is empty in Vuetify?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuetify.js

I would like to check if the user entered a date, if he didn't, he should get an error message.

I tried doing it with a rule but it doesn't show an error message.

Here is my code:

Template:

```
<v-form ref="form" v-model="valid">
<v-menu
                          :rules="birthdayRule"
                          ref="menu"
                          v-model="menu"
                          :close-on-content-click="false"
                          transition="scale-transition"
                          offset-y
                          full-width
                          min-width="290px"
                        >
                          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                            <v-text-field v-model="date" label="Birthday" readonly v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                          </template>
                          <v-date-picker
                            ref="picker"
                            v-model="date"
                            :max="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
                            min="1950-01-01"
                            @change="save"
                          ></v-date-picker>
                        </v-menu>
</v-form>

<v-btn color="primary" depressed @click="this.$refs.form.validate()">Submit</v-btn>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
       date: null,
       birthdayRule: [ v => !!v || 'Birthday required']
    };
   },


   methods: {
    save(date) {
      this.$refs.menu.save(date);
    }
   },

  watch: {
    menu(val) {
      val && setTimeout(() => (this.$refs.picker.activePicker = 
  "YEAR"));
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by putting

`:rules="birthdayRule"`

in the `<v-text-field>`tag instead of the `<v-date-picker>`tag

**Code:**

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
  <v-text-field :rules="birthdayRule" v-model="date" label="Birthday" readonly v-on="on"> 
  </v-text-field>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass that rule to v-date-picker itself instead of menu.

```
 <v-date-picker
   ref="picker"
   v-model="date"
   :max="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
   min="1950-01-01"
   @change="save"
   :rules="birthdayRule"
 ></v-date-picker>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't notice I put the rule in the wrong tag and without brackets although It still doesn't show the error message if I don't choose a date so that wasn't the problem.

Comment: @AndorNémeth Please check without array brackets,